# Validations in EntityConfiguration Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In `EntityConfiguration` is there a way where I could validate the following:

1. If its a valid email. Ex: If the email contains the @ sign.
2. If a date is within 10 days from today.

The database should not accept any value that doesn't fit the above criteria.

My Code so far:

```
        builder.Property(c => c.email)
                       .IsRequired(true)
                       .HasMaxLength(1000);

        builder.Property(c => c.persondate)
                       .IsRequired(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try registering a Value converter. When the requirements are not matched we simply write an empty string to the database. When we retrieve the values we could then filter such values out.

```
 builder.Property(c => c.email)
                   .IsRequired(true)
                   .HasMaxLength(1000)
                   .HasConversion(email => email.Contains("@") ? email : string.Empty, 
                       emailInDatabase => emailInDatabase == string.Empty ? "Non valid Email" : emailInDatabase);
```

Comment: Can we not save that value to the DB, instead display that value (the error) in the frontend ?